# Android parsing json object inside array

Tags: android, json

I want parse details of "name" and "id" here is my json and android code

```
{
  "main": {
    "details": [
      {
        "name": "name1", 
        "id": "id1"
      }, 
      {
        "name": "name2", 
        "id": "id2"
      }
     ] 
   } 
 }
```

and my code is:

```
try {
    JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(url);
    SONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("main");

    for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

        Actors actor = new Actors();
        actor.setLink(object.getString("name"));
        actor.setImage(object.getString("id"));
        actorsList.add(actor);
        }
    return true;
}
```

I want out put "id" and "name"

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try Like this:

```
JSONObject totalObject = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONObject mainObject = totalObject.getJSONObject("main");
        JSONArray jsonArray = mainObject.getJSONArray("details");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject object = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
              Actors actor = new Actors();
                actor.setLink(object.getString("name"));
                actor.setImage(object.getString("id"));
                actorsList.add(actor);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow by this way:

```
try {
JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(url);
SONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("main");

for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

    String name = object.getString("name");
    String id = object.getString("id");
    }
return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`main` is `JSONObject`, `details` is `JSONArray`, so the correct code to declare `jarray` is the following:

```
JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONObject("main").getJSONArray("details");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a JSONObject "main", containing a JSONOArray "details". This means you have to call `getJSONObject("main").getJSONArray("details");`

If you are going to such parsing multiple times, I'd recommend you to take a look at [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) - it is much easier with it. You have to set a `SerializableName` attribute to the link and image fields of the `Actor` class and Gson will take care to map them with the values from the json.